# Call method after Blazor component rerenders

Tags: callback, blazor, lifecycle

I'm doing a kind of flow chart editor.
I have a Node, which can be moved around, and has coordinates for the top-left corner:
[image]

There is an outgoing transition, the black curvy line to the bottom right, the start coordinates are calculated relative to the Node's coordinates, something like:
lineStartPosition = (Node.X + Line.StartX, Node.Y + Line.StartY)

When I click the check mark, the box expands, and moves the black dot, where the line attaches:
[image]

Because the black dot (the line attachment point) moves, I need to recalculate the Line.StartX/Y values. I have a method for that.

When I check the box, it causes the component to re-render, and then I would like the method for line coords calculation to be called, after the rerender.
I would have a method like this attached as a checkbox listener:

```
    private async Task CheckboxClicked(ChangeEventArgs args) {
        bool c = bool.Parse(args.Value.ToString());
        NodeModel.UseRandomRange = c;

        Line.ReCalcCoords();
    }
```

But, obviously the ReCalcCoords method is called before the re-render, so I get the wrong offset calculated.
I resorted to this solution:

```
    private async Task CheckboxClicked(ChangeEventArgs args) {
        bool c = bool.Parse(args.Value.ToString());
        NodeModel.UseRandomRange = c;

        await Task.Run(ExecuteNastyHack);
    }

    private void ExecuteNastyHack() {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        Line.ReCalcCoords();
    }
```

But that feels very wrong to me.
I know components has "lifecycle" methods like:
OnInitialized - But this is only called once.
OnAfterRender - But this is called all the time (probably because some other mouse-move event in my app), so that's not really usable either.

Is there a better approach?